# prevent randomly generated positions clipping canvas edge

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, drawing

i am creating a canvas filled with circles generated in random locations and having them randomly move about the canvas and change direction when then they reach the edge of the canvas. the issue im having is some of the circles are being generated part outside the canvas so they are getting stuck in the edge.

i have tried checking whether the random locations +- the radius to see if they clep the edge but this didnt seem to help the code for this is below

```
if ((x - radius > 0 || x +radius < secondCanvas.width) && (y - radius > 0 || y + radius < secondCanvas.height))
        {
            circleArray.push(new Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius))
        }
```

the code for generating the circles location is

```
var radius = 5
        var x = Math.random() * secondCanvas.width;
        var y = Math.random() * secondCanvas.height;
```

the desired result is to prevent drawn objects clipping the edge of the canvas

Comment: I think you need to replace the `||` operators with `&&`, to require all conditions to be true.
`(x - radius > 0 && x + radius < secondCanvas.width) && (y - radius > 0 && y + radius < secondCanvas.height)`

Comment: Try `var x = radius + (Math.random() * (secondCanvas.width - 2*radius));` Do the same for y

Answer (score 0):

Answer from comments, both seem to work.

```
if(x - radius > 0 && x + radius < secondCanvas.width) && (y - radius > 0 && y + radius < secondCanvas.height)


var x = radius + (Math.random() * (secondCanvas.width - 2*radius));
```